# sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:scripted-plugin_2.13:1.4.4

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

Whose problem is this and how does it get (re)solved?

My build.sbt works fine in Scala `2.12.12`

My SBT is version `1.4.4`

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
```

If however I attempt to update Scala to 2.13.4 (or 2.13.0)

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.4"
```

Then I get this in the sbt console:

```
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:scripted-plugin_2.13:1.4.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/scripted-plugin_2.13-1.4.4.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/garyhewett/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:53)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:103)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:116)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:116)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:97)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:130)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:3485)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:scripted-plugin_2.13:1.4.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/scripted-plugin_2.13-1.4.4.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/garyhewett/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.13/1.4.4/ivys/ivy.xml
```

I'm documenting the question here as I can not seem to find any references to it at all (yet) but given that there have been at least 4 upgrades in Scala 2.13 then there must be something I'm missing.

I'm using this in the libraryDependencies:

```
"org.scala-sbt" %% "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value,
```

and I think (but am not sure) I would be happy to turn "scripted" off but do not seem to be able to do so. Yes I checked the project/plugins (not there) and build.properties (not there either)

Attempts tp "turn off" scripted result in this output:

```
References to undefined settings: 

  scriptedLaunchOpts from scripted ((sbt.ScriptedPlugin.projectSettings) ScriptedPlugin.scala:99)

  scriptedBufferLog from scripted ((sbt.ScriptedPlugin.projectSettings) ScriptedPlugin.scala:99)
     Did you mean Test / g8 / scriptedBufferLog ?

  scriptedLaunchOpts from Test / g8Test ((giter8.Giter8Plugin.giter8TestSettings) Giter8Plugin.scala:102)

  scriptedBufferLog from Test / g8Test ((giter8.Giter8Plugin.giter8TestSettings) Giter8Plugin.scala:102)
     Did you mean Test / g8 / scriptedBufferLog ?
```

I have this for the resolvers:

```
    resolvers += Resolver.url("typesafe", url("https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
```

/project/build.sbt

```
sbt.version=1.4.4
```

/project.giter8.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.foundweekends.giter8" % "sbt-giter8" % "0.11.0")
```

/project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0") // 2020-Sep-29 -- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/releases
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-twirl" % "1.5.0") // 2020-Apr-03 -- https://index.scala-lang.org/playframework/twirl/twirl-api
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "1.0.0")   // 2020-May-15 -- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git
```

build.sbt

```
sbtPlugin := true
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"                                         // 2020-09-29   https://scala-lang.org/download/all.html
lazy val scalacheck = "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.2" // 2020-09-29   -- https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck/blob/master/RELEASE.markdown
parallelExecution in Test := false
lazy val lambda = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    scriptedLaunchOpts ++= List("-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m", "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m", "-Xss2m", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("typesafe", url("https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        scalacheck % Test,
        "com.github.bigwheel" %% "util-backports" % "2.1",        // 2020-Dec-11    -- https://index.scala-lang.org/bigwheel/util-backports/util-backports/1.1?target=_2.12
        "org.scala-sbt" %% "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value,  // 2020-Dec-08    -- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3514
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.11.903",   // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-kms" % "1.11.903",        // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-lambda" % "1.11.903",     // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lambda
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-rdsdata" % "1.11.903",    // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-rdsdata
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.903",         // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.1",       // 2020-Apr-29    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "3.6.0",     // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events
        "com.sun.mail" % "jakarta.mail" % "1.6.5",                // 2020-Jun-10    -- https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/ https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/smtp Latest is 1.6.5 however only 1.6.2 will load
        "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.0",                      // 2020-Mar-27    -- https://github.com/lightbend/config
        "com.twilio.sdk" % "twilio" % "8.2.0",                    // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java#using-with-a-build-automation-tool
        "com.authy" % "authy-java" % "1.5.0",                     // 2020-Aug-13    -- https://github.com/twilio/authy-java
        "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client" % "2.7.0",     // 2020-Sep-29    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client
        "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.22",              // 2020-Nov-18    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
        "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.9.1",             // 2020-Sep-29    -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json
        "com.github.cb372" %% "scalacache-caffeine" % "0.28.0",   // 2020-May-15    -- https://cb372.github.io/scalacache/docs/cache-implementations.html
        "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.21"                      // 202-May-19     -- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git (just turns off error by loading a NOOP class)

      )
  )
  .enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)                                        // 2020-Apr-03 -- https://index.scala-lang.org/playframework/twirl/twirl-api
  .enablePlugins(GitVersioning)                                   // 2020-May-15 -- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git
  .enablePlugins(GitBranchPrompt)                                 // 2020-May-15 -- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git
  .enablePlugins(ScriptedPlugin)
```

I can not seem to find any reference to scripted-plugin_2.13 in maven which leads me to think this is most likely a configuration error on my part?

To be clear my final goal is simply to update the Scala version to 2.13.4

Comment: sbt 1 is built for Scala 2.12 only; sbt 1 itself runs on 2.12 and your build definition is always itself 2.12 code, even if the code being built is some other Scala version.

Comment: Thank you @SethTisue -- this page for Scala 2.13.4 -- https://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.13.4.html points to sbt 1.4.4 Right now I don't know what I don't know so I'm probably not even asking the right question yet. I want to be able to use the Using.Manager for file/resource management and I can't get there without moving to Scala 2.13.x (or so it seems) and the above is (seems to be) a roadblock to getting there.

Comment: What goes wrong if you just remove `"org.scala-sbt" %% "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value` entirely? It doesn't sound like you know what scripted-plugin even is, so maybe you don't need it? You said "I would be happy to turn "scripted" off but do not seem to be able to do so" but it isn't clear what's stopping you? Can you share a link to your build?

Comment: @SethTisue I've added the output of my attempts to turn off scripted. Scripted appears to be part of the sbt eco system used to test of all things sbt itself. `sbt-git` might be dragging it in.

Comment: In the meantime I've resolved the need for changing the scala version by using a backport of the Util library from https://index.scala-lang.org/bigwheel/util-backports/util-backports/1.1?target=_2.12

Comment: CN you please create a repo in GitHub that reproduces the problem? For me it works perfectly.

Comment: If you're unable to share the repo on GitHub, I'd suggest ripping things out of the build until the problem goes away, then add things back one at a time to figure out what the culprit is.

Comment: @SethTisue I wish I could (NDA) however it's a big project and the moment I touch anything the likelihood of a compile will be very slim. If I start from nothing I suspect it will work so not sure which way to go. Can likely document the build.sbt however. We did achieve some relief on the major pain point and I'm no longer seeing my fleet  of lambdas going down in flames but that doesn't mean I still don't want to get to to Scala 2.13.4

Comment: I guess the person who added scripted-plugin to the build quit? Best of luck figuring it out. One more guess: is this a multi-project build? If so, perhaps there's one subproject that needs to stay on 2.12, while the rest could move to 2.13.

Comment: @SethTisue I started the project (under sbt 0.13.18) less than a year ago via a template from TypeSafe (following instructions on the web site for what I thought would lead me to a solid "current" build). So this mess is 100% mine :) Hit walls of pain trying to update beyond 0.13.18 until I took a moonshot and managed to ramp up to 1.4.4. I've added the relevant(?) project files to the question in case that sheds any light.